# Is there any method to clear Flutter app from background process too

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app, i want functionalty in that when app open it will automatically open a url in browser..when browser will open, app have to be closed automatically and clear from background too...clear from background is important to achieve

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no way to do this, Android & iOS by design prevent apps from doing this.
Also most probably Apple will reject an app that only opens a link.

Alternative to doing this is making an app widget that do this exact process and the app will be like a setting page for this widget, it will not appear on background apps when the widget opens the url in the browser, and apple will accept this app.

Note: `exite(0);` will not clear the app from background (I.ve just tried it) and Apple will consider it a crash, so they will reject the app.

Answer (score -2):

**Exit method can help**:

```
                exit(0);
```

tried calling this method, i hope this would be solve your problem.

Comment: Don't do that. The App Store will most likely remove your app if you have that code on it. That's the worst possible scenario you can "kill" an app.

Comment: i used in my app but play store did not make any issue.

Comment: It's not that you don't have any issues, the problem is that you're trying to control de OS and Android (or iOS) should be the one deciding if your app gets removed from memory or not. You can read more about it over the official docs.

Comment: ok thanks i will look on it

Answer (score -2):

I tried every method, but I think it's not possible to remove app from background (recent apps). We have to remove it manually.